# First person camera using quaternion

Tags: math, 3d, three.js, quaternions

For my first person camera in three.js, I need to limit the pitch to the range [-PI/2;PI/2].
This works fine with the example code from threejs.org using euler angles, which I rewrote to fit my needs:

```
this.pitchObj.rotation.x -= input.check("looky") * settings.mouse.sensitivityY;
this.pitchObj.rotation.x = Math.clamp(this.pitchObj.rotation.x, -HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
```

However, because I changed some things, I now need to use the quaternion version. Here the rotation works like a charm, but the pitch is not limited. So how can I write the above snippet using quaternion rotation?

My attempt:

```
this.pitchObj.rotateX(-this.input.check("looky") * settings.mouse.sensitivityY);
this.pitchObj.quaternion.x = Math.clamp(this.pitchObj.quaternion.x, -HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
```